# An inequality of standard linear parabolic equation .

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, partial-differential-equations

When I read the Evans' PDE, I get stuck in the inequality in picture below.I try to compute it as below :
$$
\int_0^T\int_{R^n}u_{tt}u_t+\int_0^T\int_{R^n}|\nabla u_t|^2=\int_0^T\int_{R^n}f_tu_t
$$
Then
$$
\int_{R^n}\frac{u_t^2}{2}|_{t=0}^{t=T}+\int_0^T\int_{R^n}|\nabla u_t|^2=\int_0^T\int_{R^n}f_tu_t
$$
Then
$$
\max\limits_{t\in[0,T]}\int_{R^n}\frac{u_t^2}{2}
+\int_0^T\int_{R^n}|\nabla u_t|^2
\le\int_0^T\int_{R^n}f_tu_t
+C\int_{R^n}\frac{(f(\cdot,0)+\Delta g)^2}{2}
$$
Then
$$
\max\limits_{t\in[0,T]}\int_{R^n}\frac{u_t^2}{2}
+\int_0^T\int_{R^n}|\nabla u_t|^2
\le\int_0^T\int_{R^n}f_tu_t
+C\int_{R^n}\frac{f(\cdot,0)^2+|\nabla^2 g|^2}{2}
$$

But I dont know how to let $\int_0^T\int_{R^n}f_tu_t$ become
 $\int_0^T\int_{R^n}f_t^2$

This picture is from 359 of Evans' Partial differential equations

> [image]

Comment: Use this inequality $ab\le \frac{\varepsilon}{2}a^2+\frac{1}{2\varepsilon}b^2$ for $u_tf_t$.

Comment: @xpaul Thanks..